# better way to make css button link

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

i've tryed making a smooth button with link tag in html and css, can i make so when people hover the button it will not show the link in bottom of the browser? and then when they click i want an option to control if it will open the link in a new tab. And maybe you can improve my button?

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Professional Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
   .button {
        background-color: #3366FF;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: lightblue;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
   }
   .button:hover {
        background-color: #0066FF;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   }
      .button:active {
     border: 1px solid #0033CC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <center>
      <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: What does "it will not show the link in button of the browser" mean?

Comment: When they hover the link they can see the page it will open. I want to disabple that, for example a button that opens a page with javascript, it will not show the page it will open.

Comment: Why? It's good they can see that. Anyway, you could use JS, but at least make it focusable (so keep it an `A` or add `tabindex`). You need onclick-to-redirect-JS? I'm sure the Google knows.

Comment: Okay, but is there anything i can do to improve the button, and do i make the html tags and css right??? I am new to code websites, i don't know much.

Comment: If it works everywhere, it's done right. Your HTML and CSS are fine. It's a pretty button. I'm not sure I understand the problem/question...

Comment: Look up the questions you are asking, they would be easy to find.

Comment: @mrphil2105 Stack Overflow is not for asking for code reviews. If it's working as intended, you could try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Otherwise, state the problem with your code.

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated in HTML and should no longer be used.

Comment: why would you want to hide the link destination? Thats the sort of link the majority of users wouldn't click, it could lead to the dark side.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can disable this behaviour as it is part of the browser. What you could do is maybe add a '#' as your href, and have the real link under a data attribute. Then when the button is clicked you redirect the user to said url using your data attribute content.

Now, everything you are asking is not user friendly at all. Removing the ability of the user to see where the link is pointing to, as well as forcing a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

**Can i make so when people hover the button it will not show the link in bottom of the browser?**

This is a default behavior of the browser, when you hover over a link it shows the destination bottom left for the user.  Sadly you can not style this and it will always show when hovering over an anchor tag with a href.  Alternatives to this would be to use a form/submit work around or use JS to redirect the user.

**When they click i want an option to control if it will open the link in a new tab**

You can use the target attribute of an anchor tag and specify _blank which will open the new link in a new tab/window (depending on the setup of the users browser)

```
<a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">Link Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

Add the href as a data attribute, like this:

```
<a class="hiddenurl" data-href="YOUR_URL">LINK_TEXT</a>
```

then in javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){

     aLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenurl");

     for(var i = 0; i < aLinks.length; i++){
         aLinks[i].onclick = function(){
             window.location.href = this.dataset.href;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You meant ClassName("hiddenurl") in our function.